# Probability with Martingales proof

Tags: measure-theory

I am working with the book ``Probability with Martingales'' by David
Williams. In the class that I am taking, we cover the following proof.

Consider $\mu$ a measure on $(S,\Sigma)$ where $S$ is a set (not
necessarilty a sample space) and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma-$algebra
on this set. We assume that $\mu$ is countably additive, i.e. 
 $$\mu(\emptyset)=0$$
  If $\{A_{i}:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ are a sequence of disjoint measurable
sets, then 
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{i}A_{i})=\sum_{i}\mu(A_{i})
$$

Finally, we form the triple $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ a measure space. We
have the following \textbf{\uline{proposition}}:

If $A_{n}\in\Sigma,$ $n\in\mathbb{N},$ then 
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}A_{n})\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{n})
$$

The proof is given as follows:

Set $B_{1}=A_{1}$and $B_{n}=A_{n}\backslash (\bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_{j})$;
$B_{n}'s$ disjoint. As such, we can use additivity and obtain:
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}B_{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_{n})
$$
 Since $B_{n}\subseteq A_{n};$ $\mu(B_{n})\leq\mu(A_{n})\leq$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{n})$

I am having some troubles with this seemingly simple proof (I think
I am missing a step):

1. The proposition itself does not specify the disjoint property \emph{anywhere
   }and it seems crucial in the proof. The proof does not seem complete
   as it does not cover cases where the disjointedness property can be
   dropped.
2. Even if we take this at face value, I don't understand how it makes
   sense whilst proving to construct a **specific** example of a set and
   prove the property for that set, and them assume that the property
   is true for all sets. I have seen it done in this course again and
   again- to prove a proposition, we construct special cases and prove
   the proposition for those cases. How can we assume that the proposition
   would hold true for all cases? In other words, when is the construction
   of a **specific** case permissible as part of a general proof?

Comment: Yes it was. I corrected it

Comment: should your $B_n$ be $B_n = A_n \backslash (\cup_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully we agree that $B_i$ are disjoint, so the stated equality holds. They neglect to mention that $\cup_n A_n=\cup_n B_n$, which gives you $\mu(\cup_n A_n)=\mu(\cup B_n)$.

The second observation is that $B_n\subset A_n$. So they're going to use $\mu(B_n)\leq \mu(A_n)$ for each term in the sum. If this isn't clear, write $A_n=B_n^c\cup B_n$ and observe that the two sets on the right are disjoint.

Comment: Thanks..I'll have to look closer at your answer.  What I don't understand is why is one allowed to create such a special case of subsets of $A$ to prove a much more general statement?

Comment: If you agree that the two families are equal in union, then that justifies it being "allowed". This is actually a common technique to write a union as a disjoint union. Each $B_n$ takes away all prior $A_i$. It's easiest if you draw a Venn Diagram to convince yourself.

Comment: @KwameBrown The motivation for rewriting the union of the $A_{n}$ as the union of the $B_{n}$ is this: we know if a countable collection of sets $\{C_{n}\}$ is pairwise disjoint, then the measure of the union is the sum of the measures, i.e., $\mu(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(C_{n})$.  If $\{C_{n}\}$ is not a *pairwise disjoint* collection of sets, we don't have this equality.  We only have $\mu(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}) \leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(C_{n})$.  In the proof, they want to use the equality, not inequality...

Comment: @KwameBrown ...So they defined the sets $B_{n}$ so that they are pairwise disjoint and you have that inequality.  So basically the proof is: we want to show $\mu(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) \leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{n})$.  Well, $\mu(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = \mu(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_{n}) \leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_{n})$ (since $B_{n} \subseteq A_{n}$ implies $\mu(B_{n}) \leq \mu(A_{n})$.